# Sublime Text 2 build system to compile & run Java in a new Terminal/Command Prompt window?

Tags: java, terminal, command-prompt, sublimetext2, build-system

I would like to make a build system in Sublime Text 2 that will compile a Java file, and then run it in a **new** Terminal (for OS X or Linux) or Command Prompt (for Windows) window.

The reason for this is because Sublime Text 2 doesn't allow users to input anything, so any programs requiring input will spit out an error when running inside Sublime Text 2, like this:

[image]

This is what I currently have (I've also tried a batch file), but it simply runs inside Sublime Text 2, as opposed to in a new shell:

[image]

Is this possible? If so, please explain, step-by-step (I'm a noob at Sublime Text 2), how to do it; I've already tried posting on the Sublime Text 2 forums, and so far no luck! I'd be inexpressibly grateful. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'd really strongly recommend using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ if you are doing Java work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the "polite" (read: short and readable) version of what I did to make this work.

- This is a starting point only. Full impl is a blog post, not an answer.
- Assumes: OS X, xterm, no package hierarchy, etc.
- Package/project stuff is *relatively* straight-forward, but IMO awkward.
- I don't have a *complete* solution that's cross-OS or that takes weird directories into account.
- My real version makes some assumptions that may or may not work for the rest of the world.
- My real version uses Ant or Maven, which solves many problems, but not all.
- Some of this can be wrapped up in the sublime-build file, but…
- …for me it's easier this way because of other stuff not shown here.

**Nutshell** (Simplification): compile and run through a shell script in order to get a new window.

**Script**

```sh
cd $1
/usr/bin/javac $2
/usr/X11/bin/xterm -e "/bin/bash -c \"/usr/bin/java $3; echo 'Press ENTER to quit...'; read line\""
```

**JavaC.sublime-build**

```js
{
  "cmd": ["~/bin/run-java.sh $file_path $file $file_base_name"],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "path": "/usr/bin/java",
  "selector": "source.java",
  "shell": true
}
```

In real life it's a bit more complex.

All this said, I never really do anything with console input in Java proper; I do it via either a Groovy or JRuby REPL, or allow stubbing of input/output sources/destinations, or… but not in Java, and not from Sublime Text 2–I use an IDE for Java development. Anything else is a waste of my time, even for short, experimental stuff.

Comment: Can you Post the Script / Build Code for windows?

Comment: @Polymorphin No, because I have no way to test.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have to use all these long methods. Well not for big projects. An example build system is

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac '$realpath$file' && java $file_base_name && rm *.class"],
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell": true,
    "variants": [

        {
            "name": "JavaDoc",
            "cmd": ["mkdir documentation && javadoc -d documentation *.java"]
        },

        {
            "name": "JAR",
            "cmd": ["javac '$realpath$file' && echo \"Main-Class: $file_base_name\" > Manifest.txt && jar cfm $file_base_name.jar Manifest.txt *.class && rm *.class && java -jar $file_base_name.jar"]
        },


    ]
}
```

This works for me on Linux and can be downloaded on Github at [Java,sublime-build](https://gist.github.com/tushortz/5fc717d4bddedf5b560b)

The interesting thing is that it also compile files to JAR. Remove classes  after compilation to make things neater and it also support generating JavaDocs.

The only limitation is that it cannot accept user input or arguments at compile time. You would have to do that manually in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you but it only works for Linux at the moment, I am still working on a Windows version . I've made a bash script for running java in sublime text 2 and 3. This script allows you to use package hierarchy but is not required.

It can be downloaded on github using this link: https://github.com/dannyvantol/JPack

If you want to pass argument you need to install GLUE for sublime text using package manage.

I don't know if the linux version works on windows with Cygwin install, But you can try it.

All the informatie you need to know how to use it can also be found on github.
I hope this was helpful for you

Comment: I have added a windows version, so you might to try it out