# How to Compile and Run Java programs that include a Import with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: java, batch-file, sublimetext2

I have Windows 7, not OS X.

I configured my Sublime Text 2 with that turorial:

[Compile and Run Java programs with Sublime Text 2](http://www.compilr.org/compile-and-run-java-programs/1251/)

It works fine with this code:

[image]

**But if i want to compile & run Code with an import, it doesn't work anymore.**

[image]

So my Question is how to configure this batch code, that i can compile & run java code which includes imports ?

```
@ECHO OFF
cd %~dp1
ECHO Compiling %~nx1.......
IF EXIST %~n1.class (
DEL %~n1.class
)
javac %~nx1
IF EXIST %~n1.class (
ECHO -----------OUTPUT-----------
java %~n1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12291655/438992

Comment: Sorry, cant use the scripts i use windows...

Comment: Presumably you're aware Windows has batch files.

Comment: Ya i know, but they are for os x and i don't understand them..

Comment: Probably better to use integer remainder rather than floating point division.  For example: ((jahr % 4 == 0) && (jahr % 100 != 0)) || (jahr % 400 == 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the following setup for running java in sublime 2, and I just tested the import function and it worked fine:

Make the bat file with the following, and save it anywhere in your PATH. I suggest C:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin\ to keep everything together.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd %~dp1
javac %~nx1
java %~n1
```

then edit C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Java\JavaC.sublime-build, the contents will be

```
{
   "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java"
}
```

replace "javac" with the name of your bat file (for instance, javacexec.bat) and save it.

Now you should be able to run it using ctrl+b.

Answer (score 1):

This package for sublime text 2 solved my problem.

https://github.com/psychowico/SublimeJavaCompiler

Features:

- JavaC: Compile Current File
- JavaC: Compile & Run Current File
- JavaC: Compile Current Project
- JavaC: Compile & Run Current Project
- JavaC: Generate Jar Package For Project
- JavaC: Generate & Run Jar Package For Project
- JavaC: Clear Project